# MSSQL Select with CASE in WHERE condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case, where-clause

I have a case where i have to select:

1. All records
2. Cancelled records
3. Open = All non cancelled records

I am trying something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Status WHERE Description =
    CASE
        WHEN @Status  = 'Cancelled' THEN 'Cancelled'
        WHEN @Status  = 'Open' THEN **NOT Cancelled**
        ELSE Description
    END
```

How to write that "NOT Cancelled" condition?

Thanks.

Comment: `THEN 'NOT Cancelled'`

Comment: You've mixed the logic of CASE with WHERE logic in a way that doesn't seem to be compatible.  You'd be better figuring it out purely as WHERE logic, as suggested below

Comment: Quick question: If the WHENs include open and not open, what qualifies as ELSE?

Answer (score 4):

Why not something like this:

```
WHERE
(@Status = 'Cancelled' AND Description = 'Cancelled')
OR
(@Status = 'Open' AND Description <> 'Cancelled')
OR
@Status NOT IN ('Open', 'Cancelled')
OR
@Status IS NULL
```

Note, that if a `Description` can be `NULL` you need to add additional logic to handle these records as `NULL = 'string'` and `NULL <> 'sting'` is false.

As Zohar Peled, pointed it can be further simplify like this:

```
WHERE
(@Status = 'Cancelled' AND Description = 'Cancelled')
OR
(@Status = 'Open' AND Description <> 'Cancelled')
OR
ISNULL(@Status, 'Open') NOT IN ('Open', 'Cancelled')
```

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: A slight simplification: `OR
ISNULL(@Status, 'Open') NOT IN ('Open', 'Cancelled')` and remove the last condition.